# SASS compiling bug - media query nested in selector stays "nested" in CSS compiled file

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

My nested media query in SASS compiles in unexpected way and I have no idea why.

I have following code:

```
.report__chart-wrap
  position: absolute
  width: 100%   
  @media(max-width: 991px)
    // position: static
  @media(min-width: 992px)
    top: 200px
    left: 90px
  @media(min-width: 1200px)
    top: 155px
    left: 0
```

Which should compile to something like:

```
.report__chart-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
@media(max-width: 991px) {}
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .report__chart-wrap {
    top: 200px;
    left: 90px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  .report__chart-wrap {
    top: 155px;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

But actually compiles to something very weird:

```
.report__chart-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  @media(max-width: 991px) {}
  @media(min-width: 992px) {
    top: 200px;
    left: 90px;
}
  @media(min-width: 1200px) {
    top: 155px;
    left: 0;
}

}
```

which obviously doesn't work.

In the same SASS file I use media queries nested in similar way which compile correctly. I use 3.2.19 sass gem and 4.0.5 sass-rails gem.

Of course I can rewrite this code and make it work, but I wanted to ask if any of you has any idea what could possibly cause this strange bug?

---

EDIT: I tested some other things since the bug reappeared in a completely different, "fresh" file.

I had something like this:

```
.class
  @media(max-width: $screen-sm-max) //variable from bootstrap gem
    width: $screen-sm-max
```

which compiled to - wait for it -

```
.class {
  @media(max-width: $screen-sm-max) { //not dereferenced variable!
    width: 991px;
  }
}
```

this.

When I interpolated the variable in nested media query:

```
.class
  @media(max-width: #{$screen-sm-max})
    width: $screen-sm-max
```

the code compiled correctly:

```
@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .class {
    width: 991px;
  }
}
```

It's weird, because it actually doesn't seem like the interpolation should be necessary in this case.

Comment: remove this line: ```@media(max-width: 991px)```

Comment: @Parhum I tried this. Nothing changed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/5835264f2d7fde35fdaf.  If you're not using the most recent version of the Ruby Sass compiler (3.4.x is the most recent), either upgrade or file a bug report with the maintainers whatever Sass compiler you're using.

Comment: I was using the sass-rails gem within the Rails asset pipeline as the default compiler. Updating it to the newest 5.0.4 version changed nothing.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem on Sassmeister, I'm afraid this question is going to have to be closed.  I can't reproduce your first example, and your second example is completely unrelated to the first.

Comment: Well you can't reproduce the problem in the different environment because clearly somehow environment is the problem here, not syntax; I can't even reproduce it myself. And reproducing it actually would be the solution, since I just want to know what causes this bug, not to fix it/find a workaround (which I have done already).

Answer (score 0):

Try write space between @media and bracket:

```
.report__chart-wrap
  position: absolute
  width: 100%
  @media (max-width: 991px)
    // position: static
  @media (min-width: 992px)
    top: 200px
    left: 90px
  @media (min-width: 1200px)
    top: 155px
    left: 0
```

It should help

Answer (score -2):

You try something like this?

```
.report__chart-wrap
  position: absolute
  width: 100%   
  @media(max-width: 991px)
    .report__chart-wrap
      // position: static
  @media(min-width: 992px)
    .report__chart-wrap
      top: 200px
      left: 90px
  @media(min-width: 1200px)
    .report__chart-wrap
      top: 155px
      left: 0
```

Comment: That's going to compile to a selector that repeats `.report__chart-wrap` (eg. `.report__chart-wrap .report__chart-wrap`).

Comment: Sorry but this isn't even a proper solution for the problem, and it definitely doesn't answer my question.